# how to manage millions/billions of small values in a "database"

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I have an application that will generate millions of date/type/value entries. we don't need to do complex queries, only for example get the average value per day of type X between date A and B.

I'm sure a normal db like mysql isn't the best to handle these sort of things, is there a better system that like these sort of data.

**EDIT**: The goal is *not* to say that relational database cannot handle my problem but to know if another type of database like key/value database, nosql, document oriented, ... can be more adapted to what i want to do.

Comment: why do you think a 'normal' db won't be able to handle this?

Comment: early optimization is root of evil.

Comment: this sounds simple enough to test, you could probably knock up a program to generate test data/test queries in an hour or 2.  why not suck it and see?

Comment: There's a big difference between a few (hundred?) millions and a few (hundred ?) billions, but we have several ~0.5 billion row MySQL tables of time based events, which isn't a problem. It'll mostly depend on the requirments of your application (data granularity, how big datasets are you querying for, how are you updating/deleting stuff, what query response times do you need etc.)

Comment: all depends on your definition of best.

Comment: if you know all of the types in advance you could just have 1 table per type with date and value, which would partition your data up

Comment: @Nishant, that quote is stupid and overused. Someone expecting this amount of records needs to optimize in the design phase.

Comment: @HLGEM I still believe looking for something more complex than MySQL is wastage of time unless you start seeing database as bottleneck in your application. It is early to discard simple solution which is most likely is going to be the solution.

Comment: @Nishant I pity the dbas who support your applications. Performance is critical in database design, databases with millions or billions of records are very difficult to refactor at the point where they show performance problems. If you do not design for the expected size of the database, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HLGEM are a million or 10s of millions records too much for a properly indexed Database? Are you seeing any answer other than using regular database? I would be interested in learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with a simple table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    [DATE] datetime,
    [TYPE] varchar(255),
    [VALUE] varchar(255)
)
```

Creating an index probably on `TYPE,DATE,VALUE` - in that order - will give you good performance on the query you've described. Use explain plan or whatever equivalent on the database you're working with to review the performance metrics. And, setup a scheduled task to defragment that index regularly - frequency will depend on how often insert, delete and update occurs.

As far as an alternative persistence store (i.e. NoSQL) you don't gain anything. NoSQL shines when you want schema-less storage. In other words you don't know the entity definitions head of time. But from what you've described, you have a very clear picture of what you want to store, which lends itself well to a relational database.

Now possibilities for scaling over time include partitioning and each `TYPE` record into a separate table. The partitioning piece could be done by type and/or date. Really would depend on the nature of the queries you're dealing with, if you typically query for values within the same year for instance, and what your database offers in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server and Oracle offer concept of [Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

In short: you could group your rows by some value, i.e. by year and month. Each group could be accessible as separate table with own index. So you can list, summarize and edit February 2011 sales without accessing all rows. Partitioned Tables complicate the database, but in case of extremely long tables it could lead to significantly better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the costs you can choose either MySQL or SQL Server, in this case you have to be clear that what do you want to achieve with the database just for storage then any RDBMS can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data as fixed length records in a file.
Do binary search on the file opened for random access to find your start and end records then sum the appropriate field for the given condition of all records between your start index and end index into the file.